# Open a model in custom viewer from BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've extracted the the folder content from bim 360:

Result

```
{
            "type": "items",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:huksL2JVQ2Gy4n4EEOY9Mg",
            "attributes": {
                "displayName": "4storeyy.ifc",
                 ...
                    "data": {
                        "sourceFileName": "4storeyy.ifc"
                    }
                }
            },
 }
```

The id (URN) is the same as the one in the URL when I view it in BIM 360.

If I use the URN in my custom viewer, it does not work.

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpkbS5saW5lYWdlOlgyOU1ydUhZUWJXV21feE1MNndLZmc=/manifest gives `not found`

Is this how you should do it if you want to read the model from BIM 360? If so, what can am I doing wrong? 
Or do I need to run download it, translate it before reading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to translate the model before being able to load it on Viewer.

Simply follow the usual steps [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/) except that you shouldn't need to download and upload the model again and can use the ID on `wipprod` for translation straight away.

Comment: Ok. So I need to setup some sort of webhook to detect when a new version is available and run a translation each time?

Comment: I get "{"diagnostic":"Failed to download the design description for the input design."}". Urn is: urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:pKwvdoEgQBC8FCEmSEDkRw .

Comment: Yes the webhook approach sounds great. Forgot to mention that the object id the translation extractor would be able to download should be the one in the storage section in your object query, e.g.: `"storage": {
          "data": {
            "type": "objects",
            "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/977d69b1-43e7-40fa-8ece-6ec4602892f3.rvt"
          }`

Comment: Ah, thx. Works. And each translation costs 0.2 || 1.5 credits?